# If $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2^2$ and $g(u)=\ln(u)$, show that $g(u)$ is a monotonic transformation of $u$ and vice versa

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**If $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2^2$ and $g(u)=\ln(u)$, show that $g(u)$ is a monotonic transformation of $u$ and vice versa.**

This is a problem in an economics course. I have taken a course in one variable calculus but I think this problem requires that the problem solver know multivariable calculus.

I thinking that if I can show that $g'(u)>0$ than $g(u)$ is a monotonic transformation of $u$. This mean that I have to find the derivative of $g$ with respect to $u$. I tried to look it up on the internet. I found the chain rule, but I have a hard time implementing it. I can't figure out how to use it on my function $g(u)=\ln(u)=\ln (x_1x_2^2)$.

**Question:** how do I differentiate $g(u)=\ln(u)=\ln (x_1x_2^2)$?

Comment: Note $dg/du=1/u$.

Comment: We have $$\partial_{x_1} (g\circ u)(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2^2}{x_1 x_2^2}$$ and $$\partial_{x_2} (g\circ u)(x_1,x_2)=\frac{2 x_1 x_2}{x_1 x_2^2}$$

Comment: I know this is bad math because I'm guessing. But I have 
$\frac{dg}{du}=\frac{dg}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+\frac{dg}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} = 1/x_1 + 2/x_2$.

Edit:  I wrote this before I saw the second comment by @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: This seems correct, right? I make an economical assumption $x_1,x_2 > 0 $. Which mathematically means that $g'(u)>0$. Therefor $g$ is a monotonically transformation of  $u$. Correct @TheSimpliFire?

Comment: Maybe clears it up a bit: You can consider $g$ as a function from $]0,\infty]$ to $\mathbb R$ that maps every $x$ to $\ln(x)$. Then $g'(x)=\frac1x$. But you can also consider $g\circ u$, where **$u$ itself is a function that depends on two variables**. Then you have to work with partial derivatives, which I gave above (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I alright, I can actually see that these two outlooks makes since. Thanks.

Comment: Put differently: Let $h=g\circ u$ (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). Then $h$ depends on **two variables**, so there is no such thing as $h'$ being a number. However, both partial derivatives of $h$ are positive (on the right domain). (In my opinion the question is badly posed because there is no canonical ordering of the set $\mathbb R^2$.)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Regarding the order: this Wass also one of my concerns. But I think it's ordering on $\mathbb R$. Because we are interested in the values of $u$ (the utility function in economics). This will make it to be an ordering on $\mathbb R$.